# Calculus Limit: mathematical syntax for multiple variables

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Is this the correct way of writing it?

$$\lim_{\substack{t \to 0^+ \\ \text{and } x \to 2^+}} \frac{x}{t}$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{(x,t)\to(2^+,0^+)}\frac{x}{t}$$ would be perfect

Comment: u are the best i <3 u

Comment: @user1561559: i $<3$ u too ;)